# What does "she was as generous in sharing her death as she was in sharing her life" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I just started reading this book called "A Dirty Job" by Christopher Moore. The author has dedicated his work to Patricia Moss by this sentence:

> This book is dedicated to Patricia Moss, who was as generous in sharing her death as she was in sharing her life".

I don't exactly get the meaning of it. Is there any kind of irony in this sentence? Does the writer want to say "She not only shared her life with others when she was alive, but also, when she died, she was still generous and shared her death with others and killed them"? or the writer only wants to praise Patricia Moss?

Comment: You’ll have to ask the author, I’m afraid. I doubt the intention is that she killed others after she was dead, but the statement itself is not clear. It is certainly not idiomatic and a matter of English language usage; it is just an obscure statement.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of literature, not about the English Language per se.

Comment: Well you'd need to know how Patricia Moss died, perhaps she wrote about her sufferings. I would Google her up and see if my hunch is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> As with any book, I owe a debt of gratitude to those who helped
>   inspire the book, as well as those who actually helped in the research
>   and production.
>
> For inspiration, my deepest thanks to the family and friends of
>   Patricia Moss, who shared their thoughts and feelings during the time
>   of Pat's passing. Also thanks to the hospice workers in all
>   capacities, who share their lives and hearts every day with the dying
>   and their families. http://www.rulit.net/books/a-dirty-job-read-75193-83.html

He is speaking of the process of death -its intimate nature, and Moore is recognizing this concept was more difficult than sharing the details of one's life.